# Count tr in table using parent

Tags: jquery, parent, tablerow, closest

I need to count the number of rows in a table.
I need them to be counted as the user clicks an image inside a `<td>`

So far I've tried something like this:

```
$(".up, .down").click(function(){
var rows = $(this).closest('table').find('tr').length;
});
```

.up and .down are the class of the images clicked
For practical reasons the table does not have an ID...
It seems like it takes the first table - not the closest...

--- added ---

```
    <table class='bokse'><tr>
<tr sideid='7' sidepos='1'>
<td><h3 class='link' pid='7'>Formål</h2></td>
<td><img src='btn/op.png' class='up' title='ryk op' alt='op' /> <img src='btn/ned.png' class='down' title='ryk ned' alt='ned' /> <img src='btn/vis.png' class='vis' item='page_7' title='vis' alt='vis' /></td>
</tr>
<tr sideid='8' sidepos='2'>
<td><h3 class='link' pid='8'>Vedtægter</h2></td>
<td><img src='btn/op.png' class='up' title='ryk op' alt='op' /> <img src='btn/ned.png' class='down' title='ryk ned' alt='ned' /> <img src='btn/vis.png' class='vis' item='page_8' title='vis' alt='vis' /></td>
</tr>
<tr sideid='10' sidepos='3'>
<td><h3 class='link' pid='10'>Bliv medlem</h2></td>
<td><img src='btn/op.png' class='up' title='ryk op' alt='op' /> <img src='btn/ned.png' class='down' title='ryk ned' alt='ned' /> <img src='btn/vis.png' class='vis' item='page_10' title='vis' alt='vis' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are a series of tables like this with various lengths.
Each is nested inside another table.

Though the number of rows varies, it says there are 4 rows - as in the first table - regardless of which I click

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?  Or at least post your html?

Comment: That should work, what is the problem?

Comment: For practical reasons, like counting the TRs in an entire table, an ID should be added to the table element.

Comment: try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/135/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of an extra `<tr>` at the begnining.
remove the first `<tr>` which does not have an end `</tr>`. `<table class='bokse'><tr>`
See this http://jsfiddle.net/3PM9M/

```
$(".up, .down").click(function(){

    alert('total rows -' + $(this).parents('table').find('tr').length); //Gives all the tr's
    alert('Clicked row -' + (parseInt($(this).parents('tr').index()) + 1)); // clicked tr's index
});
```

Comment: Well spotted PSCoder... now I'm just feeling a tiny bit stupid here ;)